# All products and categories side-menu on one page

Tags: magento-2.1, products, category-view

I want to display all my store products on one page, with a side menu to 'filter' on the available categories.
Basicly the same view as a single categorie product list, but then with all products (of Default Category) and all main categories on the side bar. 
I've been searching the internet for two days and haven't found any (working) solution.

I'm using Magento 2.1, with a premium paid theme (Porto).

I've tried creating a page with this code as content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="all.products.list" alias="products_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

and adding XML in the design field.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name>
</action>
</block>
</reference>
```

However, the XML gets rejected and the content code doesn't show any products.

Is this such a 'hard' thing to do?
I would expect Magento just having an overview of all products somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are using the Magento 1 code that will not work on Magneto2.

Add these xml and try it.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>


                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
        </referenceContainer>


    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Using this code, I first get an error on the <attribute... part. When I only insert the top referenceContainer, it gives me "Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" errors on the page. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: remove `<attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>` this line and check.

Comment: Still getting these errors:
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container does not exist

Comment: @roy.stultiens I tested this code it is working fine without any error

Comment: Could it be something with a messed up Magento installation?
I copy/pasted the code, removed the `<attribute />` line and when trying to  view the result, the magento exceptions come up.

Comment: @roy.stultiens remove the attribute part `<attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>` because this xml is not allowed in design. else work perfectly.

Comment: I can't get it to work... Still get the error that the class doesn't exist (this is in the first container block). If the second referenceContainer works and shows the side menu.

Comment: @roy.stultiens check with default theme of magento. and try to remove var/generation folder too

Comment: Got it to work!
Removed the entire block containing the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container class.
This does result in the output I require. Thank you very much!